# Undefined variable $students - This always come up. can someone help me about this problem

Tags: laravel, search, routes, controller, fetch

HERE'S CONTROLLER:

```
public function search(Request $request){

    $search = $request->search;

    $students = StudentsList::where('Student_no','Like','%'.$search.'%')->first();

    return view('front.vendors.login_register')->with(compact('students'));
    }
```

HERE'S ROUTE:

```
Route::get('search/studno','VendorController@search');
```

HERE'S BLADE FILE:

```
  <input type="text" id="vendorfname" name="Fname" 
          class="text-field" value="{{$students['Fname']}}" 
          readonly="">
```

Comment: When i try to re open the page it alway says  (Undefined variable $students)

Comment: I want to fetch the searched data in input field please send help

Comment: <input type="text" id="vendorfname" name="Fname" class="text-field" value="{{ $students['Fname']}}" readonly="">

Comment: I've also tried this but still same problem coming up
   <input type="text" id="vendorfname" name="Fname" class="text-field" value="{{ $students->Fname}}" readonly="">

Comment: You use $studentsList in your blade without compact the value of $studentsList from controller.

Comment: its $students sir not $studentsList

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using [`compact`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) and sometimes $students might be false. Please use `with` instead of compact.

Comment: SEARCH BUTTON
    <form id="vendorSearch" action="{{ url('/search/studno') }}" method="get">@csrf
                    <div class="searchpanel">
                        <input class="searchbox" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search Your Student No." aria-label="Search" required="">
                        <input type="submit" class="searchbtn"  value="Search"></button>
                   </div>
                </form>

Comment: Here's my code in search button